# Error from use of C# Linq SQL CONCAT

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, concatenation

I have the following three tables, and need to bring in information from two dissimilar tables.

- Table `baTable` has fields `OrderNumber` and `Position`.
- Table `accessTable` has fields `OrderNumber` and `ProcessSequence` (among others)
- Table `historyTable` has fields `OrderNumber` and `Time` (among others).

.

```
var progress = from ba in baTable                                   
           from ac in accessTable
           where ac.OrderNumber == ba.OrderNumber
           select new {
                Position = ba.Position.ToString(),
                Time = "", 
                Seq = ac.ProcessSequence.ToString()
           };
progress = progress.Concat(from ba in baTable
                       from hs in historyTable
                       where hs.OrderNumber == ba.OrderNumber
                       select new {
                           Position = ba.Position.ToString(),
                           Time = String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", hs.Time),
                           Seq = ""
                       });
int searchRecs = progress.Count();
```

The query compiles successfully, but when the SQL executes during the call to `Count()`, I get an error

> **All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must  have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.**

Clearly the two lists each have three items, one of which is a constant.  Other help boards suggested that the Visual Studio 2010 C# compiler was optimizing out the constants, and I have experimented with alternatives to the constants.

The most surprising thing is that, if the `Time=` entry within the `select new {...}` is commented out in both of the sub-queries, no error occurs when the SQL executes.

Comment: Try changing `Time = String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", hs.Time)` to `Time = "foo"`

Answer (score 1):

I actually think the problem is that Sql won't recognize your String.Format(..) method.

Change your second query to:

```
progress = progress.Concat(from ba in baTable
                       from hs in historyTable
                       where hs.OrderNumber == ba.OrderNumber
                       select new {
                           Position = ba.Position.ToString(),
                           Time = hs.Time.ToString(),
                           Seq = ""
                       });
```

After that you could always loop trough the progress and format the Time to your needs.